# Java swing weird extra pixels in drawRect

Tags: java, swing

I have stumbled on a weird issue with graphics `drawRect` - it adds two extra pixels at the bottom left and bottom right of the rectangular shape.
Is this a VM problem? or something in my understanding is wrong?
I am running this on windows 8.1 64bit java SE 1.8.0_25.

**EDIT:** I have edited the code to do proper override of `paintComponent`.
Also I have noticed that when the window first appears, I do see the content as in the attached screenshot (with the extra pixels), but when I resize it to a smaller window and back (thus forcing the EDT to repaint the whole panel again) - the pixels vanish and do not reappear in subsequent window resizing.
I Even added `fillRect` to minimize the effect of artifacts (if any), but still, to no avail.

I don't know what to make of it.

**EDIT 2:** SSCCE modified to run from EDT - still same results

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GuiTest extends JFrame
{
    public GuiTest()
    {
        super( "Test" );

        setContentPane( new MyPanel() );
        setSize( new Dimension( 200, 200 ) );
        setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new GuiTest();
            }
        } );
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel
    {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent( Graphics g )
        {
            super.paintComponent( g );
            g.setColor( Color.WHITE );
            g.fillRect( 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() );
            g.setColor( Color.BLACK );
            g.drawRect( 10, 10, 100, 100 );
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: check your graphics driver

Comment: This runs perfectly fine using `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26) / Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)` but on Linux/Ubuntu.

Comment: Its not aliasing and it happens on a different computer with a different type of graphics adapter.

Comment: Override `paintComponent` iso `paint` and call `super.paintComponent`, as illustrated in the [Custom paint tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html)

Comment: @Robin: I appreciate your answer and I fully understand the swing paint mechanism. This was only to illustrate the problem with a code example. The lack of calls to super and the usage of paint() are not the cause of it. It looks like a VM bug - but I wanted to confer with all of you before addressing oracle.

Comment: `I appreciate your answer and I fully understand the swing paint mechanism` then post proper painting code. The point of creating a SSCCE is to show that you are following the Swing standards and to rule out the possibility that your shortcut is causing the problem. There is no point for us to test your code because the painting code is not correct and may cause artifacts because the background is NOT properly cleared before the custom painting is done.

Comment: @camickr: you are absolutely right - SSCCE updated (please checkout the resizing comment too), thank you.

Comment: Run this on the EDT(Event Dispatch Thread), all GUI code should run on it, failing to do so can cause unpredictable behavior.

Comment: @MSB: good point - I've modified the SSCCE but still same results

Comment: Also, works on Windows 7, JDK build 1.7.0_60-b19. Would seem like a bug to me if you can reproduce it on different computers.

Answer (score 1):

Ha!
I have just noticed that this is a hardware acceleration issue.
If I turn it off by using `-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false` then everything seems to paint normally - without the extra pixels.
I have checked my display adapter (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 850M) driver (as per @Fast Snail suggested) and and it is up-to-date.
This is weird - yet still, with no answer, the origin of the problem is at least clear.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting what I think is a related problem, but affecting width only, and only in the case of rectangles which are extremely shallow, but it lops some pixels off the width...  Java Swing Graphics drawRect, drawRoundRect, etc. all drop some pixels from the right of the rectangle.

I tried @Extremely 's suggestion re hardware acceleration, and it didn't make any difference.

I have increased the width parameter by 12 (!) in these drawRoundRect and fillRoundRect calls, and it works perfectly! Yuk!

On second thoughts, I think this is a rather different problem - I will raise a separate question.  Thanks!